# Join arrays together according to their values

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Lets say i have these 3 different arrays;

```
int[] arr1= new int[2] {7,9};

int[] arr2= new int[2] {1,5};

int[] arr3= new int[2] {5,7};
```

Their order will be always random so in my case following is the same thing therefore i just cant do something like "arr2+arr3+arr1". I need to check second value and find it in other's first value.

```
int[] arr1= new int[2] {5,7};

int[] arr2= new int[2] {1,5};

int[] arr3= new int[2] {7,9};
```

How can i merge them in a way that i will have resulting array;

{1,5,5,7,7,9}

And for the next step i need to check following condition

```
int[] arr1= new int[2] {5,9};

int[] arr2= new int[2] {1,5};

int[] arr3= new int[2] {7,9};
```

Since this wont create intended resulting array, i need to throw warning. I will be using c# for my project but you can answer in C or java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int[] final = arr1.Concat(arr2).Concat(arr3).OrderBy(v => v).ToArray();`

Comment: @RayFischer I couldnt come up with any idea. I tried to write some work arounds on paper but i ended up with lots of loops so didnt try any.

Comment: @Gusman thanks for the answer, i will try tomorrow morning and let you know if that works.

Comment: @Gusman thanks, it worked!

Comment: What is the logic in your joining? I assume it is not just sorting in order (which Gusman's solution is) because then it would work equally for your last example (giving 1,5,5,7,9,9) whereas you have said the second example should give a warning. It looks to me like it is a bit like dominos where the last digit of one array matches the first of the next but you are very unclear on this. You need to be very clear in what you want to be able to get answers that actually work as you want them to. Two examples, only one of which works does not speify your problem sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Gusman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162699/gusman)'s comment:

```
int[] final = arr1.Concat(arr2).Concat(arr3).OrderBy(v => v).ToArray();
```

Using `.Concat(arr2)` method on `arr1` joins the two arrays and returns a new array which has a combination of their values.

Now this new array is combined with `arr3`, again returns a new array which has all values of the previous arrays.

The new array is now passed to the `.OrderBy()` extension method... which uses an lambda expression (you can investigate more on lambda expressions). This concrete lambda expression takes every element (the left side of =>) in the array and sorts it "as itself" (the right side of =>)

Comment: I don't think it is just ordering by the elements. I think it is joining the arrays with the second number of one array being the first number in the next. This is why the second set of arrays given throws a warning instead of the number sorted in order.

Comment: Aha you are reffering to his second step, sorry, completely forgot about that one while answering... Now that I think about it I'm not sure about the question at all... Shall I remove the answer?

Comment: Yeah, the question is very unclear though. I'm not really sure that my interpretation is right but I *think* that it is. :)